# List files from browserify bundle

Tags: browserify

How can I see a list of all files found and bundled using the API, much like browserify's `--list` command-line option?

```js
var browserify = require('browserify');
var b = browserify('main.js').bundle();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can listen to the `dep` event, which is triggered for every dependency going through the pipeline:

```
var b = browserify('main.js');
b.on('dep', function(dep) {
  console.log(dep.file);
});
b.bundle();
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it, not a direct solution but the only foreseeable one.

When `browserify('main.js').bundle()` is called, browserify looks recursively through each of the required files and triggers any stream handlers set via `b.pipeline.get('deps').push()` when each file is found/read.

```js
var dependencies = '';

b.pipeline.get('deps').push(through.obj(function(row, enc, next) {
    dependencies += (row.file || row.id) + '\n';
    this.push(row);
    next();
}));
```